# need to create subdomains in Azure DNS from ASP.NET Core dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I need to create subdomains in Azure DNS from ASP.NET Core dynamically so that the users who needs to create their own subdomains can do it as we see in most of the web apps out there like wix, etc..

Could anyone please detail the right steps well explained?

Thanks.

Comment: Another option would be to use wildcard at DNS level, then apply some kind of client routing below that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a management SDK for Azure, which you can use inside your ASP.NET Core application.

[Create DNS zones and record sets using the .NET SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-sdk) - this is detailed full tutorial for this.

Code will be similar to this, though you will probably use CNAMEs instead of A records

```cs
// Create record set parameters
var recordSetParams = new RecordSet();
recordSetParams.TTL = 3600;

// Add records to the record set parameter object.  In this case, we'll add a record of type 'A'
recordSetParams.ARecords = new List<ARecord>();
recordSetParams.ARecords.Add(new ARecord("1.2.3.4"));

// Add metadata to the record set.  Similar to Azure Resource Manager tags, this is optional and you can add multiple metadata name/value pairs
recordSetParams.Metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
recordSetParams.Metadata.Add("user", "Mary");

// Create the actual record set in Azure DNS
// Note: no ETAG checks specified, will overwrite existing record set if one exists
var recordSet = await dnsClient.RecordSets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, zoneName, recordSetName, RecordType.A, recordSetParams);
```